# in c # i need to write a program to measure bandwidth usage per day, week, month etc

Tags: networking, bandwidth

How do I go about do this. What API (microsoft and non-microsoft are available) to achieve this?

Comment: I think this is ready made available in your hosting servers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking IIS you can use [log parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) to process the logs and then store the restuls in some kind of DB. It has an API that can be accessed via c#, you just need to reference it in visual studio. There are examples in the documentation.